# create additional selectboxes with value of other selectbox

Tags: jquery

How can i add the same number of selectboxes with different id, that is choosen by another selectbox value  ?

If is choosed option 3, 3 new selectboxes should be created.
If is choosed option 2, 2 new selectboxes should be created.
...
I hope you understand.

Can someone help me please? Thank you a lot!

```
<select name="children" id="children">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
...
</select>
<div id="add_select">
...and below should be new created with jquery...

<select name="children" id="child-1-age">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
...
</select>

<select name="children" id="child-2-age">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
...
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery clone is what u need

Comment: You could even try construct the select tag within a loop which would loop till the no of count value from the first list box.... this way you can even think of adding unique id`s to the dynamically getting created List boxes

Comment: Set the actual `value` attribute of your initial select list options, then you can use that value in a for loop, and create the other lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With clone, you can create a template and copy it `x` number of times. I documented my code, hope it will be enough to understand :

```
$('#children').change(function(){
    var $div = $('#add_select'), //Select the appending div
        $select = $('<select/>', {name : 'children'}), //Create a template
        index = this.selectedIndex; //get the number of select

    $div.empty(); //Erase old select

    if(!index) return; //Stop the code if the number of child is 0

    for(var i=0; i<14; i++){ //Maximum child age
        var $option = $('<option/>', {text : i, value : i});//Create the option element
        $select.append($option);//Append to the template
    }

    for(var u=0; u<index; u++){//Get the number of child
        var $clone = $select.clone(); //Clone the template
        $clone.attr('id', 'child-'+(u+1)+'-age').appendTo($div); //Change its id and append to the container
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

Here the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NCLae/1/

Answer (score 1):

use [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

just to get you strated

```
$('#children').change(function(){
     var $this=$(this);
     var cloneItem=$(this).val();
     for(var i=1;i<=cloneItem;i++){ 
         var clonedItem=$this.clone().find('select').attr('id','child'+i+'-age').end();
         $('#add_select').html(clonedItem);

     }
});
```

or

```
$('#children').change(function(){
 var $this=$(this);
 var cloneItem=$(this).val();
 for(var i=1;i<=cloneItem;i++){ 
     var clonedItem=$this.clone();
     clonedItem.attr('id','child'+i+'-age');
     $('#add_select').html(clonedItem);

 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try below code:

```
$('#children').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < selected; i++) {
        var idd = "add_select-" + selected+ "-age";
        $('#children').clone().attr('id', idd).appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq5jq/164/).